# route-me RMMarker Label is not show in 4

Tags: route-me

using Route-me show offline map, i show a customer view set into RMMarker(method:[marker setLabel:myView];) ,it can be show in ios 3.2, but not show in ios4.x. what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Need more of your code if you're still having this problem.   RMMarkers are working fine on my machine(tm) with ios 4 and betas of 5.

Ciao!

-- Randy